# How do you describe a nut which does not tighten

Tags: word-request

Suppose that you want to use a pair of bolt and nut to connect two things. However, the nut is like you can screw it forever and does not tighten!

What do you call this kind of nuts?
Is there an adjective for them?

I would say ***the nut is broken***, but I am not sure if that's the most common way of saying that.

Comment: FWIW, the nut could be fine and the bolt could be bad.

Comment: The nut is not "broken" - it could simply be a mismatch with the bolt where the thread pitch is the same but the diameter is subtly different.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I would say:

> The thread has been stripped.

That is to say, the thread on either the nut or bolt has become damaged and can no longer support the load applied by the opposite thread:

[image]

Comment: Right, screws of any kind are said to be stripped. Or alternatively, you can say threads are worn.

Comment: @Lambie Though "worn" is much less specific.

Comment: Stripped is completely useless; worn is on the verge of being so.

Comment: This is correct. You can also be more specific about the damage to the thread (the spiral ridges in your picture). Stripped means the spirals are gone or worn so low they no longer grip. On the bolt, they can occasionally get bent so you might say the thread is damaged or bent or whatever. Very rarely a nut may get partly crushed so the inner part is no longer circular in which case you might say it is "out of true".

Comment: Generally when I hear "Stripped" in the context of a screw I would assume that it means the slot for the screwdriver has been damaged and the tool can't get the grip to turn the screw. Not that the screw's thread is damaged. But a Stripped bolt does make sense in this context.

Comment: Worth adding that, in the same context and to the opposite, a nut and bolt that won't turn at all can be called 'seized'.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 while wood screws generally don't get stripped in this manner (losing their thread), it's not that uncommon with machine screws, where the mating metal piece is also metal

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 that's the *head* being stripped, while Lee Mac says the *thread* is stripped (as I would).  The equivalent to a stripped head on a nut on hex-head bolt would be something like *rounded off*, by the way

Comment: @Lambie 'Stripped' is the correct adjective. Go to any construction site or machine / mechanical shop and this is the most common way to describe this in the parlance of our time, no contest.

Answer (score 8):

In New Zealand and Australia we use the adjective *munted* to describe something (or someone) no longer capable of functioning, particularly screws, nuts and bolts that have been damaged by someone forcefully trying to turn them with the wrong tool. It is now more often used to describe people who are too intoxicated to function properly.

Comment: I am a 67yo Australian and I have never heard the word 'munted' in my life.

Comment: Something about 'munted' makes me immediately understand what it means!

Comment: Whereas in England "munted" means "off your face" or "very drunk" / incapacitated, as used in Shaun Of The Dead.

Comment: *not to be confused with a munter.

Comment: @JohnU I can think of plenty of words meaning both "broken" and "incapacitated" a few of them may even be usable in poltie company.  Slightly differently there's [*knackered* (UK)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knackered) =worn out/fatigued/(of a horse etc.) ready to be slaughtered

Comment: @ChrisH - so can I, but referring to a mechanical fastener as _drunk_ doesn't quite fit, hence I would say _munted_ is not a good fit here.

Comment: Never heard it in the UK either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That just means you don't know enough chavs.  Heard it plenty in London, though it seems it may be something brought to the UK from NZ/Aus.  It's definitely a newer word - didn't really feature prior to the '90s.

Comment: @J... Maybe it's a London thing. Only been two or three times.

Comment: @J...[possibly how it got to UK?](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2011-03-17/william-tours-munted-christchurch/2653616)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is slang.  It also doesn't apply specifically to a stripped thread - a nut or a bolt can be munted in so many other ways.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would say

> dodgy, broken, loose

I think outside of engineering most people would be grasping for some kind of synonym of *broken*

Comment: The problem with "broken" is that people are more likely to assume that it's cracked or broken into multiple pieces.

Comment: To me, saying it's "loose" implies that it can be tightened, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Good points guys, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The nut is **worn out**. Or you can say *This nut's threads are worn out*.

> Something that is worn out can no longer be used because it is so old or because it has been damaged by continued use:

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worn-out)

> Damaged or shabby to the point of being no longer usable.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worn_out)

Answer (score 0):

There is also **crossthreaded**.  This probably isn't quite what you're going for, but it's related.  In this case it feels tight and will not turn easily, but because the nut's threads and the bolt's threads are not properly aligned, it's not holding on with the desired strength.